# Seek bar position scale error

Tags: android, xml, seekbar

I setup a seekbar and set the position using margin left and top. I need the seekvar to be vertical so I rotated by 270. I want to position the seekbar in the rotated position all the way to the right side of the view but the seekbar travel gets smaller the closer I get to the end and overrides the android:layout_width.  V Android 4.0.3

```
    <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarDimmer"
    android:layout_marginLeft="880dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@color/slider"
    android:thumb="@drawable/sliderred"
    android:rotation="270"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using marginLeft and marginTop to set the position. I think you should better use relative layout and using the attribute   android:layout_alignParentRight="true" you can make the seekbar all the way to the right side of the view. Also use (negative value) android:layout_marginRight less than half the size of the seekbar width to make it on the right side.

I think you are looking something like this..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<SeekBar
android:id="@+id/seekBarDimmer"
android:layout_width="270dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginRight="-120dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:rotation="270"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```